# How to create a user created Character a array while printing it out

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

Whenever I run this code. I get the least understandable output I probably have ever received. Please help I've been struggling with this for a very long time. Thanks.

```
int main()
{
char letters[50];
char y;
char Character;
char test='t';

for(int x=0;x<50;x++)
{
    while (isalpha(test))
    {


    cout<<"Enter letters to add to the array and any number  to stop"<<endl;
    cin>>letters[x];
    test=letters[x];

    }
    x=51;
    cin.ignore();
    cin.clear();

}
for (int x=0;x<50;x++)
{
    cout<<letters[x]<<" ";
}
cout<<endl;


return 0;
}
```

[image: pls help picture]

Answer (score 0):

Your `while (isalpha(test))` loop is inside the `for(int x=0;x<50;x++)` loop, so `x` is always `0` and you keep replacing the first character until you input a digit, and all other characters don't ever get initialized.

Answer (score 0):

> A C-style string is simply an array of characters that uses a null
>   terminator. A null terminator is a special character (‘\0’, ascii code
>   0) used to indicate the end of the string. More generically, A C-style
>   string is called a null-terminated string.

When you use character arrays to store C-style strings, You should know something about it

1.Array of character is pointer to a character that point to the address array started from

2.That's contain some character and cpp don't initial values of array and be contain some data

If you want to initial data you have many way

the best way to fill it with zero

```
char letters[50] = {0};
```

Or you can initialize a character array with a string literal (i.e. a string in double quotes), as long as you leave room for the null character in the allocated space.

```
char letters[50] = "Johnny";
```

Notice that this would be equivalent to:

```
   char letters[50] = {'J', 'o', 'h', 'n', 'n', 'y', '\0'};
```

3.The functions like printf in c and cout in argument get pointer to character that point the start of character array start.And print array to '\0' character for example

```
int main()
{
    char letters[50] = {'A', 'M' , 'I' , 'N' , '\0' , '1'};

    /*
        ------------------------------------------
        | A | M | I | N | \0 |   |   |   |   |   |
        ------------------------------------------*/

    cout << letters; //output: AMIN 
    return 0;
}
```

And Last for solving the problem

Only assign '\0' (A null terminator) to end of your C-style string.Like below for your question

```
int main()
{
    char letters[50];
    char y;
    char Character;
    char test = 't';
    int x = 0;
    while ( isalpha(test) && x<49)
    {
        cout << "Enter letters to add to the array and any number  to stop" << endl;
        cin >> letters[x];
        test = letters[x];
        x++;
    }
    cin.ignore();
    cin.clear();
    letters[x] = '\0';

    cout << letters<< " ";
    cout << endl;


    return 0;
}
```